# Undefined body in Node/Express API using bodyParser when accessed by fetch or axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, body-parser

I'm making a call to an API in Node/Express in a React app, and regardless of where I put the fetch/axios call, my parsed body shows as undefined in my controller. I spent yesterday working with fetch, but tried axios for a change today, and here's the request:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in',
    data: {
        email: "matthewharp@gmail.com",
        password: "xxxxxxx"
    }
})
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Now, here's the tricky part: `console.log()` statements in the Node controller AND the query file do trigger, so there's not a problem with the routing, and when I configure the query file to simply send a resource at random, ignoring the intended logic of searching by a body field, everything returns fine. But both fetch and axios result in `undefined` values for the `req.body` and any attribute therein. For instance, this action in the controller:

```
signIn(req, res, next) {
    let user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    console.log("1: " + Object.keys(req.body));
    console.log("2: " + req.body.email);
}
```

Will result in the following log to the console:

```
1: [object Object]
2: undefined
```

But a call to `Object.keys()` for the object in question returns an empty string.

I am using bodyParser, but as other questions have pointed out, that must be initialized before any route declaration - which I'm doing (I've abstracted configuration into a `main-config.js` file and a `route-config.js` files, and main contains bodyParser and is initialized first).

I'd greatly appreciate any help, and will happily provide more information and code snippets.

Edit: API code https://github.com/RainyDayMatt/abbas-tables-node-express-api/tree/mrh-add-user-code

Comment: Can you share your API code?

Comment: I can share whatever would help, but it's abstracted. Can you be more specific? Or I could share my branch.

Comment: Just added a link to my branch.

Comment: Can you just post a link to the API code in here?  Much easier than switching between tabs/windows

Answer (score 3):

So, I had implemented bodyParser incompletely. I had set up `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))` when initializing my main config file, but not `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.